# "Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported" when building OpenSSL

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, openssl, nmake

I am trying to build OpenSSL from source (branch OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable) using Visual C++ (Visual Studio 2015 is installed) by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable/INSTALL.W32).

When I run `nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak` I get the following output:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Building OpenSSL
        perl util/copy.pl ".\crypto\buildinf.h" "tmp32dll\buildinf.h"
Copying: ./crypto/buildinf.h to tmp32dll/buildinf.h
        perl util/copy.pl ".\crypto\opensslconf.h" "inc32\openssl\opensslconf.h"
Copying: ./crypto/opensslconf.h to inc32/openssl/opensslconf.h
        cl /Fotmp32dll\uplink.obj -Iinc32 -Itmp32dll /MD /Ox /O2 /Ob2 -DOPENSSL_THREADS  -DDSO_WIN32 -W3 -Gs0 -GF -Gy -nologo -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDIAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DOPENSSL_USE_APPLINK -I. -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE /Zi /Fdtmp32dll/lib -D_WINDLL  -c ms\uplink.c
uplink.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(205): fatal error C1189: #error:  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64_arm\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

My `ms/ntdll.mak` file content:

```
# This makefile has been automatically generated from the OpenSSL distribution.
# This single makefile will build the complete OpenSSL distribution and
# by default leave the 'interesting' output files in .\out and the stuff
# that needs deleting in .\tmp.
# The file was generated by running 'make makefile.one', which
# does a 'make files', which writes all the environment variables from all
# the makefiles to the file call MINFO.  This file is used by
# util\mk1mf.pl to generate makefile.one.
# The 'makefile per directory' system suites me when developing this
# library and also so I can 'distribute' indervidual library sections.
# The one monster makefile better suits building in non-unix
# environments.

INSTALLTOP=D:\TelegramDesktop\Libraries\openssl\Release
OPENSSLDIR=D:\TelegramDesktop\Libraries\openssl\Release\ssl

# Set your compiler options
PLATFORM=VC-WIN32
CC=cl
CFLAG= /MD /Ox /O2 /Ob2 -DOPENSSL_THREADS  -DDSO_WIN32 -W3 -Gs0 -GF -Gy -nologo -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDIAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DOPENSSL_USE_APPLINK -I. -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE    
APP_CFLAG= /Zi /Fd$(TMP_D)/app
LIB_CFLAG= /Zi /Fd$(TMP_D)/lib -D_WINDLL
SHLIB_CFLAG=
APP_EX_OBJ=setargv.obj $(OBJ_D)\applink.obj /implib:$(TMP_D)\junk.lib
SHLIB_EX_OBJ=
# add extra libraries to this define, for solaris -lsocket -lnsl would
# be added
EX_LIBS=ws2_32.lib gdi32.lib advapi32.lib crypt32.lib user32.lib

# The OpenSSL directory
SRC_D=.

LINK_CMD=link
LFLAGS=/nologo /subsystem:console /opt:ref /debug
RSC=rc

# The output directory for everything intersting
OUT_D=out32dll
# The output directory for all the temporary muck
TMP_D=tmp32dll
# The output directory for the header files
INC_D=inc32
INCO_D=inc32\openssl

PERL=perl
CP=$(PERL) util/copy.pl
RM=del /Q
RANLIB=
MKDIR=$(PERL) util/mkdir-p.pl
MKLIB=lib /nologo
MLFLAGS= /nologo /subsystem:console /opt:ref /debug /dll
ASM=ml /nologo /Cp /coff /c /Cx /Zi

# FIPS validated module and support file locations

FIPSDIR=\usr\local\ssl\fips-2.0
BASEADDR=0xFB00000
FIPSLIB_D=$(FIPSDIR)\lib
FIPS_PREMAIN_SRC=$(FIPSLIB_D)\fips_premain.c
O_FIPSCANISTER=$(FIPSLIB_D)\fipscanister.lib
FIPS_SHA1_EXE=$(FIPSDIR)\bin\fips_standalone_sha1.exe
E_PREMAIN_DSO=fips_premain_dso
PREMAIN_DSO_EXE=$(BIN_D)\fips_premain_dso.exe
FIPSLINK=$(PERL) $(FIPSDIR)\bin\fipslink.pl
```

Running `nmake -f ms\nt.mak` produces the same error.

I am not sure why building for platform VC-WIN32 leads to an error about ARM platform. Also, I haven't find any question about this error on VS2015, only VS2013 and below, in which compiling for ARM platform is really not supported.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you are under an ARM developer prompt. Visual Studio installs four or five different developer prompts. Pick the x86 developer prompt.

Comment: @jww You are right. In fact, I found out that this was the solution before (and answered the question...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out what was wrong:

I have run the commands in `VS2015 x64 ARM Cross Tools Command Prompt` instead of in `VS2015 x86 Native Cross Tools Command Prompt`.

Running in `VS2015 x86 Native Cross Tools Command Prompt` solved the issue.